# Html form update flask route and dom

Tags: javascript, dom, flask

I have a form which can take "Player A" and "Player B" names. Once the user clicks "Start Game", the game starts (which has been implemented as a flask route /players). However, upon clicking "Start Game", I also would like the "player-text" be updated with the player names. This is my attempt so far, but does not work. My d3.click does not recognize the event. Is there some way to do both? Thanks.

index.html:

```
<div>
<form method="POST" action="/players" role="form", name="playerform">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="playerA">Player A</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="playerA" name="playerA" placeholder="Player A">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="playerB">Player B</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="playerB" name="playerB" placeholder="Player B">
   </div>
   <input type="submit" id="playerform" name="playerform" value="Start Game" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
</form>
</div>
<div id = "player-text"> </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../static/game.js"></script>
```

app.py:

```
@app.route("/players", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def send():
    global ds_game
    if request.method == "POST":
        playerA = request.form["playerA"]
        playerB = request.form["playerB"]
        #return jsonify({"playerA":playerA, "playerB" : playerB})
        return redirect("/index", code=302)
```

game.js

```
d3.select("#playerform")
    .on("click", function(){
        console.log("Clikecd on player form")
        d3.json("/show",($dict)=> {
            let $scores = $dict["scores"]
            let $player = $dict["player"]
            d3.select("#player_score").remove();
            d3.select("#player-text").append("div").attr("id","player_score")
            .append("p").attr("align","center").html($player)
            .append("p").attr("align","center").html($scores);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Not sure of what you're trying to accomplish, the page reloads after clicking on the form, right?

Comment: Yes, the page reloads. On clicking the submit button to "Start Game", I want it to 1. go through the flask route for "players" and also 2. update the "#player-text" div with some html. I am able to do only #1 with above code. The game.js code is not updating the #player-text div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that, once you send the form, the data that you collected with js is lost because js is just reloaded again along with the page.

What you could do is storing the values you want to render using the `session` object of flask and using them in the template you return in the redirected path.

Like this:

```
# ...
from flask import session

# Session needs SECRET_KEY to be set
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'something secure'

# ...
def send():
  # ...
  session['players'] = {
    'A': playerA,
    'B': playerB
  }

# ...
def index():
  # ...
  return render_template('template.html', players=session['players'])
```

And in your template file you could reference them.

```
<!-- ... -->
<div id="player-text">
  {% if players %}
  <p>{{ players['A'] }}</p>
  <p>{{ players['B'] }}</p>
  {% endif %}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. Somehow I was hesitant to use jinja.